# HttpClient.PostAsync always returns 404

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a Xamarin.Forms Application that attempts to post data to a Web API. (Web API 2 & MVC).

The problem I'm having is that my HttpResponse always returns a 404 - even when I know the application can contect to the server. (Getting data is fine, posting isn't.)

The Xamarin Code: (Client Side - ignore the return types of the methods, I've removed a lot of the business logic!)

```
    //Method that passes the route and param to getChartData()
    private BarChartModel getChartData ()
    {
        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (this);
        string chartData = FRAPI.GetDataWithData ("BARCHART/GETBARCHART/", postData);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BarChartModel> (chartData);
    }


    //method that connects to the web api.
    public static string GetDataWithData (string route, string data)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient ())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri (APIRoot);

            var content = new StringContent (data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync (route, content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
            }
            else {//blah}
        }
    }
```

API - Server Side Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/BarChart/GetBarChart/{data}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBarChart(string data)
    {
        try
        {
           BarChart barChart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BarChart>(data, GlobalSettings.JsonSettings);
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "true");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The Route Configuration:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

It's worth mentioning that I've tried a number of variations of the server side code, including:

- Removing the `{data}` part from the route. (The tutorial posted below has a similar route and doesn't include the route.)
- Including the `[FromBody]` tag in the method signature.

From what I can see, my code doesn't actually differ (aside from object names) from the `resgisterUser` code in this [tutorial.](https://github.com/guardinfo-spam/XamarinRestServicesTutorial)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have `APIRoot` setup properly?  Have you tried putting the full URL in the code instead of constructing it?

Comment: what url is your Xamarin app trying to hit?  Have you tried looking at the call via `Fiddler`?

Comment: `APIRoot` is also used for the retrieval of data, which works perfectly!

Comment: Also why are you mapping routes in your config and using `RouteAttribute`s?

Comment: Ahh... to fix this I should have took my own advice and changed the method signature to 'FromBody' AND removed the `{data}` part from the route.
Now my only problem is the actual body of the request is empty. But thats a different problem for a different day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between your code and the example is that your code receives a `string` which you try to deserialize. You should let ASP.Net do the deserializing for you. In other words, change the code like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/BarChart/GetBarChart")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetBarChart(BarChart barChart)
{
    try
    {
       Debug.WriteLine(barChart);
       // do something useful with the barChart...
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "true");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and ASP.Net will deserialize the request's body to `BarChart` (provided you send a json that matches `BarChart` type).

By the way: naming a method `GetBarChart` while you are actually `POST`-ing to it is somewhat misleading.